# PHP - Permission issue writing image to localhost

Tags: php

I am getting an error using curl to download an image to my localhost. I've made sure the permissions are good and the directory exists. I'm at a loss for what to check next. This is the error I'm getting

```
Warning: unlink(images/) [function.unlink]: Operation not permitted in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/image/instapaper.php on line 47
```

Here is my code:

```
 $saveto = 'images/';

if ( !file_exists($saveto) ) {
 mkdir ($saveto, 0777, true);
}

    $url = 'http://img.ffffound.com/static-data/assets/6/4dea2e91338b67cd926140acde1962403c3bf4c2_m.jpg';

echo getcwd() . "\n";

$ch = curl_init ($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
$raw=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
if(file_exists($saveto) && is_writable($saveto)){
    unlink($saveto);
}
$fp = fopen($saveto,'x');


if(fwrite($fp, $raw)==false){
  echo 'no dice';
  return;
}
fclose($fp);
```

**SOLVED

Below is the working code. It basically looks like I was trying to save the image as the directory location I had specified. That's been cleared up and I've got an image name provided to save the file to. In the final script the image name will be taken from the url.

```
    $url = 'http://img.ffffound.com/static-data/assets/6/4dea2e91338b67cd926140acde1962403c3bf4c2_m.jpg';
$saveto = 'images/';
$image_name = 'image.jpg';
$full_path = $saveto .  $image_name;

if ( !file_exists($saveto) ) {
 mkdir ($saveto, 0777, true);
}

$ch = curl_init ($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
$raw=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
if(file_exists($full_path) && is_writable($full_path)){
    unlink($full_path);
}
$fp = fopen($full_path,'x');


if(fwrite($fp, $raw)==false){
  echo 'no dice';
  return;
}
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: You create directory and try remove category unlink($saveto) - what is reason ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$saveto` is a directory - you can't `unlink()` it, you must `rmdir()` it.

Comment: Thanks this helped me figure out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The warning is with `unlink`, not the cURL. And it looks like you're trying to do it to a directory, and that's not permitted, and, according to the docs, a failure will produce a warning.

You can use `rmdir($dirname)` to remove a directory, but as well as the proper permissions, the directory must be empty for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Well for starter unlink() is to remove files, rmdir() is to remove directories. Also the directory must be empty.

When I look at this warning: "Warning: unlink(images/)" it looks like you're trying to delete a folder with the wrong function.